Possible to update a User-Initiated Send to target a different email?
Basically what I'm trying to do is set up an automation with a send definition and be able to update which email that send definition sends out.
Automation runs on a weekly basis so I want to be able to programmatically change which email gets sent out each week without having to manually modify the send definition/activity.
For example, if my send definition/activity is sending "Sample_Email1" this week then next week I want to be able to programmatically change it to "Sample_Email2".
Is this possible?

90% of your question is answered here (lower code example): Automate deployment activity via API or SSJS to Pause, Save and Resume API Event journey after a change to the Email tempate
You can programmatically interact with "TriggeredSendDefinition" using SOAP API. WSProxy emulates the SOAP API, meaning you can use it, as seen in the link (pause  / publish  / restart is already done).
That is good news as it will be reducing a lot of overhead.
All that remains is updating the email in the triggeredSend while paused;
You can update using WSProxy:
https://www.ssjsdocs.xyz/email-studio/triggeredsends/update.html
To understand how, you need to find how TriggeredSend references the email it uses. In the docs linked above you will see the Email Property: TSDefinition documentation references the "Email" Object.
Meaning after programmatically pausing the TS, you can update its "Email" property - you'd have to test which email ID you can use for the update, either Email.Id (which I would guess) or Email.CustomerKey; After the update, publish and restart as seen in first link.
The update would then be something along the lines of:
var config = {
    Name: "MyUpdatedTSD",
    CustomerKey: "S0M3-GU1D-K3Y-G03SR1G4T-H3R3",
    Email.Id:"id of my new email"
};

var result = prox.updateItem("TriggeredSendDefinition", config);

